# wp_title() not working properly with blog in non-root folder

Tags: wordpress

I followed this guide to have my blog appear under `mydomain.com/blog`:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Your_Blog_Appear_in_a_Non-Root_Folder

In short, I'm using a custom page template to create a static page "Blog", which then goes and renders the posts:

```php
<?php
/*
Template Name: Blog
*/

// Which page of the blog are we on?
$paged = get_query_var('paged');
query_posts('cat=-0&paged='.$paged);

// make posts print only the first part with a link to rest of the post.
global $more;
$more = 0;

//load index to show blog
load_template(TEMPLATEPATH . '/index.php');
?>
```

In my theme, I render the `<title>` tag using the following syntax:

```php
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> | <?php is_front_page() ? bloginfo('description') : wp_title(''); ?></title>
```

This is described here in the codex:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title#Covering_Homepage

The problem is that now on mydomain.com/blog, there is no title rendered by wp_title('');

If I stop using the blog.php template, then the title appears correctly. Obviously the blog posts do not anymore though. How to have the wp_title() display the correct title in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be following the updated guide for Wordpress 2.1+:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page

Comment: Ahhhh, so THAT'S what this "Posts page" setting is for in the reading settings!